# Get token with all claims using a custom value with IdentityServer

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I need to request a token with all the claims of a specific user.

The authentication is made by a third party so I don't have the password of the user. In the context, I do have an unique id of the user, let's call it **user_id**.

I have the **client_id** and it's secret.

I'm using IdentityServer v3.

By using OAuth2 I can get an access token by using the **IdentityServer STS address**, **client_id** and the **secret** of the client.

Is there a way to get all the claims of an user by passing the **user_id** and the **accessToken**?

- Is this an insecure way?
- Am I violating any OAuth or ClientID standard?
- Is there an endpoint for this and I'm not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

[IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) supports [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/), so you can get a user's claims by requesting IdentityServer to issue an **[ID token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)** which contains a user's claims.

If IdentityServer supports **[userinfo endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo)**, which is a part of [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), you can get an ID token from the endpoint, too.